# Unmet dependency after linux mint distribution update

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dependencies

I have recently updated to Linux mint rebecca. I am getting unmet dependencies for `apt-get`

when I am trying to `apt-get install` a package named `monodevelop-nunit monodoc-nunit-manual` then this happens.

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop-nunit monodoc-nunit-manual
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mint-mdm-themes : Depends: mint-mdm-themes-html but it is not going to be installed
 monodevelop-nunit : Depends: libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnunit-core2.6.3-cil but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnunit-util2.6.3-cil but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

then I do this

```
 apt-get -f install  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mint-mdm-themes-html
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mint-mdm-themes-html
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 24.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 438154 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mint-mdm-themes-html_1.8.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking mint-mdm-themes-html (1.8.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mint-mdm-themes-html_1.8.3_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mdm/html-themes/SpaceRace/ship3.png', which is also in package mdm-html5-themes-samriggs 0.1.3~debian+dmdc
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mint-mdm-themes-html_1.8.3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

then

```
apt-cache policy mint-mdm-themes-html
mint-mdm-themes-html:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.8.3
  Version table:
     1.8.3 0
        700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/main i386 Packages
```

my source.list is like this

```
 cat /etc/apt/sources.list
 # deb http://apt.jenslody.de/ any main
  # deb-src http://apt.jenslody.de/ any main
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release i386 20131126]/ saucy contrib main non-free   deb http://apt.wxwidgets.org/ squeeze-wx main
```

how can I resolve it?

Comment: sudo dpkg --remove mdm-html5-themes-samriggs